# ASP.NET Routing Interference Problems

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, dynamic-data, asp.net-routing

I'm having a mind shattering problem with ASP .NET routing. I can't tell if this is a bug in Microsoft code or if I'm just using it wrong.

The scenario is basically this:

I have a custom route I want to add. In addition, I'm registering ASP .NET `DynamicDataRoute`s. If I leave out my custom route, all the ASP .NET `DynamicDataRoute`s work fine. Once I add this before my `DynamicDataRoute`:

```
routes.Add(new Route("IgnoreDirectory/{*pathInfo}"), new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

all the DynamicHyperlinks generated by DynamicData are generated with the wrong root url, like this one:

http://localhost/IgnoreDirectory/MyTable/List

which should be (and was until I added my custom route)

http://localhost/MyDynamicData/MyTable/List

What's weird is that I'm adding my DynamicDataRoute for a COMPLETELY different path:

```
routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("MyDynamicData/{{table}}/{{action}}")
                {
                    Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert" }),
                    Model = model
                });
```

Why is adding a route for IgnoreDirectory causing my DynamicData routes to use a base url of IgnoreDirectory????

I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here, but I think it has to do with two things. The order that the routes are stored in the RouteTable are significant in that the application will use the [first route it finds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.aspx) in order to match the URL.

What I think might be happening here is that the DynamicDataRoute is building itself upon the Route that you are inserting before the DynamicDataRoute in the route table.

The first thing I would do is try moving the Route add after the DynamicDataRoute has been added.

Hope this helps...

Comment: You're right, that does help!...but what I don't understand is why the DynamicDataRoute is building itself on a route that maps to a COMPLETELY different path (IgnoreDirectory).... Can you elaborate on why a route for a completely different directory would interfere?

Comment: Based on my very limited understanding (hopefully not totally wrong) of the way DynamicDataRoutes work is that they will build themselves off of the Routes that come before them in the RouteTable. If you want them to be based on the root (~/) they should be before any other Routes in the RouteTable.